# Vertex Overlapping in OpenGL

Tags: opengl

here is the code which draws a cylinder primitive :

```
glBegin(GL_TRIANGLE_FAN);
glVertex3f(0, height / 2.0f, 0);
for (int i = 0; i < SIDENUMS +1; i++)
{
    glVertex3f(radius * cos(i * 2 * PI / SIDENUMS), height / 2.0f, radius * sin(i * 2 * PI / SIDENUMS));
}
glEnd();

glBegin(GL_QUADS);
for (int i = 0; i < SIDENUMS + 1;i++)
{
    glVertex3f(radius * cos(i * 2 * PI / SIDENUMS), height / 2.0f, radius * sin(i * 2 * PI / SIDENUMS));
    glVertex3f(radius * cos(i * 2 * PI / SIDENUMS), -height / 2.0f, radius * sin(i * 2 * PI / SIDENUMS));
    glVertex3f(radius * cos((i+1) * 2 * PI / SIDENUMS), -height / 2.0f, radius * sin((i+1) * 2 * PI / SIDENUMS));
    glVertex3f(radius * cos((i+1) * 2 * PI / SIDENUMS), height / 2.0f, radius * sin((i+1) * 2 * PI / SIDENUMS));    
}
glEnd();

glBegin(GL_TRIANGLE_FAN);
glVertex3f(0, -height / 2.0f, 0);
for (int i = 0; i < SIDENUMS + 1; i++)
{
    glVertex3f(radius * cos(i * 2 * PI / SIDENUMS), -height / 2.0f, radius * sin(i * 2 * PI / SIDENUMS));
}
glEnd();
```

And the output is something like image below :

[image]

Now in picture , please note on Point A.

This point has drawn two times , one in TRIANGLE_FAN and second in GL_QUADS , My question is that , is this two distinct points welded automatically to each other to make a one point ? or they are on top of each other ? In summary how many points are there ? one or two ?  how can I fix if they are not welded to each other?

Answer (score 0):

> is this two distinct points welded automatically to each other to make a one point ?

Nope.

> or they are on top of each other ?

Yep.

> how many points are there ? one or two ?

Two.

You'll have to fuse vertices client-side if that's important to you.  There's no magic coalescing in OpenGL.

Comment: can u give an example to fuse and weld them ! how can I draw them welded ?

Comment: @S.A.Parkhid: This is nothing that OpenGL does OpenGL just plats points, lines and triangles to the screen, and then forgot about how they came to be. There is no such thing like a "scene" or models in OpenGL. "merging" or "fusing" the points would be something that happens in the data structures of your program. However for the shape you showed it actually makes little sense for a *shared* vertex, since the *normals* of the faces drawn are different.

Comment: I think there are more like three vertices at point A in this diagram. There are a couple of quads that have a vertex at that location and a couple of fanned triangles. The fanned triangles reuse one vertex, but the quads create two distinct vertices.

Answer (score 0):

The triangle fan primitives re-use "points" when creating the triangles, but for quads each call to `glVertex3f (...)` is generating a single "point."

To put this another way:

When you use triangle fans, the first triangle requires 3 vertices to be transformed, each following triangle only requires 1 new vertex (and reuses 2). This matters for [post-T&L cache](http://www.opengl.org/wiki/Post_Transform_Cache) efficiency, which is the concept you were ultimately getting at in your question.

When you use vertex arrays and `glDrawElements (...)` or primitive modes that share vertices (e.g. fans and strips) you can avoid having to transform the same point multiple times. If you were using more per-vertex attributes than you have in your example, however, this might not be practical. That is, if each of the sides of the object you are drawing had a different set of texture coordinates or normals for the same spatial location.